# css stylesheet vs template

Tags: css

I'm just starting out on the web development, when someone tells me if they are providing css stylesheet / template is that the same thing. does the template only give me the way my page looks and do I have to map html to the css to replicate site similar to that? If someone can provide me an example it would be really great. Thanks!

Comment: As the answers have suggested we really need more context to explain what a template is.  But to answer your first question, it is highly unlikely that "template" and "stylesheet" refer to the same thing.

Comment: The best plan is just to wait and see what they provide you with. Or if it's going to be sometime, then ask them to provide you with an early draft or outline,

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a **specific**, answerable, **programming** issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 3):

A template can have a wide range of meanings in the world of web development. It can mean anything from simple HTML markup that is used when rendering data to a full website built out in HTML, JavaScript, and CSS that you can adapt to your needs.

I think in your context, the person you are talking to is saying they will provide the CSS style sheets (that give you the look and feel of the website) as well as example HTML pages to show you how to utilize the various components. The [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework is a good example of this type of template. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) itself is primarily just CSS and JavaScript, but they provide you with many examples of HTML so you can understand how to utilize the available components.

Answer (score 1):

> when someone tells me if they are providing css stylesheet / template is that the same thing?

When someone tells you something and you're unsure of what they're telling you, it's appropriate to **ask them** to clarify.

No one on Stack Overflow can answer with certainty some vague statement by some other unknown developer.

> does the template only give me the the way my page looks and do I have to map html to the css to replicate site similar to that?

So lets back up a bit and discuss jargon.

In common web-developer parlance "stylesheets" refer to CSS stylesheets, and "templates" refer to example HTML structures that can be reused with different data.

An example `widget` template might look like

```
<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget__header">Header of the widget</div>
  <img class="widget__image" src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/>
  <div class="widget__description">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

In this example, the HTML contents and attributes may be updated to show a widget with any sort of content that you'd like.

---

All that said: different tools/products/server-side languages have different jargon. One CMS I use calls the structured server-side code "templates" whereas another calls the data structures themselves "templates", so context is important.

Answer (score 0):

A template is generally HTML markup while a stylesheet is a separate CSS file used for styling the template. You can think of the template as the house and the stylesheet as the paint and wall paper.

Answer (score 0):

A template is usually a set of html, css, images, js and other files, which gives you a particular look and feel. Whoever told you that perhaps wanted to let you know that you don't need to work much on styling, as those things are already done.

Answer (score 0):

A stylesheet defines how your elements will look.

Some HTML

```
<div class="my-title-section">
   <h1>My Title</h1>
</div>

<div class="my-content-section">
    Some content here
</div>
```

This content can then be changed visually using styles relating to the above content and its assigned classes.

```
.my-title-section { 
        font-size:150%;
}

.my-content-section {
        padding:20px;
        background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Here you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/5p0mae5e/